# ruby regex named and group

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to use a named group in a regex but it doesn't work:

```
module Parser
  def fill(line, pattern)
    if /\s#{pattern}\:\s*(\w+)\s*\;/ =~ line
      puts Regexp.last_match[1]
      #self.send("#{pattern}=", value)
    end
    if /\s#{pattern}\:\s*(?<value>\w+)\s*\;/ =~ line
      puts value
      #self.send("#{pattern}=", value)
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see I first test my regex then I try to use the same regex with a named group.

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :name, :type, :visible
  include Parser #add instance method (use extend if we need class method)
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @type = "image"
    @visible = true
  end
end

t = Test.new("toto")
s='desciption{ name: "toto.test"; type: RECT; mouse_events: 0;'
puts t.type
t.fill(s, "type")
puts t.type
```

When I execute this, the first regex work but not the second with the named group.
Here is the output:

```
./ruby_mixin_test.rb
image
RECT
./ruby_mixin_test.rb:11:in `fill': undefined local variable or method `value' for 
#<Test:0x00000001a572c8> (NameError)
from ./ruby_mixin_test.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If [`=~`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E) is used with a regexp literal with named captures, captured strings (or nil) is assigned to local variables named by the capture names.

```
/(?<lhs>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<rhs>\w+)/ =~ "  x = y  "
p lhs    #=> "x"
p rhs    #=> "y"
```

But - *A regexp interpolation, `#{}`, also disables the assignment.*

```
rhs_pat = /(?<rhs>\w+)/
/(?<lhs>\w+)\s*=\s*#{rhs_pat}/ =~ "x = y"
lhs    # undefined local variable
```

In your case from the below code :

```
if /\s#{pattern}\:\s*(?<value>\w+)\s*\;/ =~ line
   puts value
   #self.send("#{pattern}=", value)
end
```

Look at the line below, you use **interpolation**

```
/\s#{pattern}\:\s*(?<value>\w+)\s*\;/ =~ line
 ~~^
```

Thus *local variable assignment* didn't happen and you got the error as you reported *undefined local variable or method 'value'*.

Comment: your answer is very ineresting. Have you some sources please?

Comment: If you are looking for a solution, then it seems from tinkering that although `lhs` is not set, `$~[:lhs]` **is**, so perhaps that is the best workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `value` in the module

```
if /\s#{pattern}\:\s*(?<value>\w+)\s*\;/ =~ line
  puts value  # This is not defined anywhere
  [..]
```